# Problema para sacar porcentaje con valor en array

Tags: c#, array, bucle-for, condiciones

necesito calcular la comisión de cada venta, según el valor de la venta se saca un porcentaje distinto según sea el caso, y al final necesito que me muestre el total de la comisión de la venta sumado con el sueldo base que es de 500000.

El problema es que no me está haciendo bien las operaciones con los porcentajes para sacar las comisiones. No me saca el porcentaje de la comisión correcto.

Creo que el problema está dentro de este método:

```
public void bonificacion()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ventas.Length; i++)
        {

            if (ventas[i] <= 400000)
            {
                comision = ventas[i] * 0.03;
                comisiones[i] = comision;
            }
            else if (ventas[i] > 400000 && valorVenta < 800000)
            {
                comision = ventas[i] * 0.05;
                comisiones[i] = comision;
            }
            else if (ventas[i] >= 800000)
            {
                comision = ventas[i] * 0.10;
                comisiones[i] = comision;
            }

            totalEmpleado = comisiones.Sum() + 500000;
            empleados[i] = totalEmpleado;
        }
    }
```

No se cual pueda ser el problema, igual aca dejo el codigo completo. Se los agradeceria mucho si me pudieran ayudar. Gracias.

```
    int contVentasBajas = 0, contVentasMedias = 0, contVentasAltas = 0; 
    int numEmpleados, numComisiones, valorVenta;
    double comision, totalEmpleado, totalVenta;
    double[] totalVentas;
    double[] ventas;
    double[] empleados;
    double[] comisiones;

    public void establecerParametros()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de empleados");
        numEmpleados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        empleados = new double[numEmpleados];
        totalVentas = new double[numEmpleados];
    }

    public void ventasRealizadas()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < empleados.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de ventas de este vendedor");
            numComisiones = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            ventas = new double[numComisiones];
            comisiones = new double[numComisiones];

            for (int j = 0; j < ventas.Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor de la venta");
                ventas[j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (ventas[j] <= 300000)
                {
                    contVentasBajas++;
                } 
                else if (ventas[j] > 300000 && ventas[j] < 800000)
                {
                    contVentasMedias++;
                } 
                else if (ventas[j] >= 800000)
                {
                    contVentasAltas++;
                }

                totalVenta = ventas.Sum();
                totalVentas[i] = totalVenta;
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    public void bonificacion()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ventas.Length; i++)
        {

            if (ventas[i] <= 400000)
            {
                comision = ventas[i] * 0.03;
                comisiones[i] = comision;
            }
            else if (ventas[i] > 400000 && valorVenta < 800000)
            {
                comision = ventas[i] * 0.05;
                comisiones[i] = comision;
            }
            else if (ventas[i] >= 800000)
            {
                comision = ventas[i] * 0.10;
                comisiones[i] = comision;
            }

            totalEmpleado = comisiones.Sum() + 500000;
            empleados[i] = totalEmpleado;
        }
    }

    public void mostrarInforme()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < empleados.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Venta total del empleado: " + totalVentas[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("Comision empleado: " + empleados[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ventas menores a 300000: " + contVentasBajas);
        Console.WriteLine("Ventas entre 300000 y 800000: " + contVentasMedias);
        Console.WriteLine("Ventas mayores a 800000: " + contVentasAltas);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Agrego lo que aparece en consola.

[image: Lo que muestra en consola]

Comment: ", lo que pasa es que no me esta haciendo bien las operaciones con los porcentajes para sacar las comisiones." porque? cual es el valor que sale? cual es el valor que deberia salir? seguiste tu codigo a ver como hace los calculos? no podemos corregir algo que no sabemos que tiene que dar ni como...

Comment: Hola, si tiene toda la razon, no explique bien mi problema, ya edite, espero hacerme entender un poco mejor

Comment: Y otra vez, cual es el problema??? tu programa anda... que anda mal? que deberia dar?

Comment: como se ve en la imagen de la consola el programa anda, pero donde dice comision empleado me arroja un valor que no deberia, por ejemplo si hice una venta de 900mil, la comision es del 10% osea 90mil asi que deberia arrojarme 590mil porque lo sumo al sueldo base que es de 500mil, pero arroja un valor que nada que ver por ejemplo 506mil

Comment: ok.. esto es c#, y es super facil hacer un debug y ver que valores hay en cada punto, cosa que no vamos a poder hacer por vos.. saber hacer debug??? porque esto es facil de ver.... para nosotros, sin tener un programa funcional.. imposible...

Comment: esto = empleados[i] = totalEmpleado; esta mal... estas guardando en el empleado i... que si estas dentro de una iteracion, es cualquier cosa... le estas asignado valores a cualquier cosa...

Comment: Si se que es un debug, solo que estoy empezando a programar y aun no se usarlo bien. Lo que estoy intentando guardar en empleados[i]=totalEmpleado es la comision de cada empleado para luego imprimir el array, si me esta guardando los valores creo que el error esta en las operaciones o tal vez es mi logica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás utilizando 4 matrices diferentes para almacenar los datos, hacer eso al final complica el 'casar' los datos, por ejemplo:

```
empleados = [1, 2, 3]; 
ventas = [100, 50, 68, 194, 85]; 
comisiones = [25, 6, 8, 9, 5];
```

Si utilizas varios arreglos para almacenar datos que tienen relación, entonces ¿cómo saber cuáles son las ventas y comisiones del empleado 2? Por ejemplo.

Para resolver la problemática planteada, te sugiero que utilices un sólo arreglo de 2 dimensiones.

De esta forma, podrás guardar las ventas en la columna 1 y las comisiones en la columna 2. de esta forma cada fila representaría un empleado y está contendría toda su información. Te dejo el código:

```
    readonly int sueldoBase = 500000;
    int contVentasBajas = 0, contVentasMedias = 0, contVentasAltas = 0;
    int numEmpleados, numVentas;
    double[,] datos;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.EstablecerParametros();
    }

    public void EstablecerParametros()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de empleados:");
        numEmpleados = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        datos = new double[numEmpleados, 2];
        VentasRealizadas();
    }

    public void VentasRealizadas()
    {
        for (int e = 0; e < numEmpleados; e++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero de ventas del empleado {0}:", e + 1);
            numVentas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int v = 0; v < numVentas; v++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Empleado {0} - Ingrese el valor de la venta {1}:", e + 1, v + 1);
                Double valor = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Bonificacion(e, valor);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
        MostrarInforme();
    }

    public void Bonificacion(int e, double valor)
    {
        datos[e, 0] += valor; // Almacenamos el acomulado de la venta en la columna 0
        
        if (valor <= 400000)
        {
            datos[e, 1] += valor * 0.03; // Almacenamos el acomulado de la comision en la columna 1
            contVentasBajas++;
        }
        else if (valor > 400000 && valor < 800000)
        {
            datos[e, 1] += valor * 0.05; // Almacenamos el acomulado de la comision en la columna 1
            contVentasMedias++;
        }
        else if (valor >= 800000)
        {
            datos[e, 1] += valor * 0.10; // Almacenamos el acomulado de la comision en la columna 1
            contVentasAltas++;
        }
    }

    public void MostrarInforme()
    {
        for (int e = 0; e < numEmpleados; e++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Venta total del empleado {0}: {1} ", e + 1, datos[e, 0]);
            Console.WriteLine("Comision del empleado {0}: {1}", e + 1, datos[e, 1]);
            Console.WriteLine("Comision mas sueldo base del empleado {0}: {1}", e + 1, datos[e, 1] + sueldoBase); // Sumamos el sueldoBase a la comisión del empleado
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ventas menores o iguales a $400,000: " + contVentasBajas);
        Console.WriteLine("Ventas entre $400,000 y $800,000: " + contVentasMedias);
        Console.WriteLine("Ventas mayores o iguales a $800,000: " + contVentasAltas);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo en responder, efectivamente si funciono el programa como lo dejaste, apenas estoy aprendiendo y me sirve mucho saber donde estaba mi error.